# Multi round annotation processing with kapt

Tags: kotlin, annotations, kapt

I have written an annotation processor which generates some Kotlin code which itself has annotations which require processing by another processor.

As kapt doesn't support multi-round annotation processing I have to build then re-build my project to have the annotations on the generated code be processed. This works but is inconvenient and non-obvious.

How can I get kapt to run twice? (Even if this requires a custom build task or similar).

Comment: have you figured out a solution for this?

Comment: I didn't, what I do is: `gradle clean compileKotlin && gradle compileKotlin` and that works for me

Comment: That should work indeedn but also think about `automation`